# Surface area common to two perpendicularly intersecting cylinders

Tags: definite-integrals, vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals

I need help to calculate the following surface area:

> the surface area common to the two cylinders $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ and $x^2 + z^2 = a^2$ **using surface integrals essentially**.

My attempt: Let surface area = $S$ and $\hat n = \nabla(x^2 + y^2) = \frac{1}{a}(x \hat i + y \hat j)$
$$S = \int \int ds = \int \int \frac{dy dz}{|\hat n\cdot\hat i|}$$
$$= \int \int \frac{a}{x}dy dz$$
$$= \int \int \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 - y^2}}dy dz$$

How do I progress from here on?

Comment: [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html)

Comment: @achillehui I saw the result there. But can you show me the way in my attempt? I will be very happy if you help me. I need it very much.

Comment: Using symmetry, split the surface into four pieces which give equal contribution to the area. On one of the piece, say the one with $x > 0, |z| \le \sqrt{a^2-y^2}, |y| \le a$. If you integrate the $z$ term first, you will obtain a factor $2\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$ which cancel the corresponding one in denominator. The integral become trivial after that.

Comment: @achillehui Very very thanks.  Can you help me solve another question of mine.... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476246/surface-integral-over-a-cone .....I will be eagerly waiting for your reply. Please help.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat can you please explain how did you solve the problem i am also stuck on this. Why did you take the gradient of x²+y² surface for the area , the common area of the enclosed region is of a domical type so it's surface wouldn't be different. Can you please tell about the integration and symmetry conditions also please..