# Evaluate Surface integral: $\vec F=y{\hat i}+x{\hat j}+zy{\hat k}$, S is part of $z=x^2+y^2$ above $z=1$. Assume S has an upwards orientation.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

I want to evaluate ${\int}{\int_S}{\vec F}\cdot d{\vec S}$ with the given information in the title but cannot for the life of me figure this one out. I have looked at Stoke's theorem, and also the divergence theorem but they do not seem to fit, given my knowledge of multivariable-calculus.

I've been trying to use this fact:
$${\int}{\int_S}{\vec F}\cdot d{\vec S}={\int}{\int_D}{\vec F} \cdot({\vec r}_u \times {\vec r}_v)dA$$ but I cannot figure out how to parameterize and also get the limits on integration for that, if it is even applicable. If I could figure out ${\vec r}(u,v)$ and the limits of integration then this problem is not hard but I can't.

If anyone could spare a few moments to help me I would really appreciate it. Sorry that I do not have any work to show but I am utterly stuck on this question and would love to solve it.

Thank you.

Here's an example sort of like mine but it is bounded top and bottom: [Surface Integral over a cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476246/surface-integral-over-a-cone)

Comment: It is a cone. Use cilindric coordinates.

Comment: @kmitov I understand that, but that still does not help me set anything up. Would you parameterize it with cylindrical coordinates? How?

Answer (score 1):

The surface $S$ is part of a rotational paraboloid. Use the following parametrization:
$$S:\quad (u,v)\mapsto{\bf r}(u,v):=(u\cos v,u\sin v,u^2)$$
with parameter domain $D:=[1,\infty[\>\times\>[0,2\pi]$.

Make sure that ${\bf r}_u\times{\bf r}_v$ has $z$-component $>0$, and then compute the final integrand for your  surface integral by plugging in the parametrization of $S$ into the definition of $\vec F$ and expressing ${\bf r}_u\times{\bf r}_v$ in terms of the parameters as well (that's what is called *pullback*):
$$\psi(u,v):=\vec F\bigl({\bf r}(u,v)\bigr)\cdot\bigl({\bf r}_u(u,v)\times{\bf r}_v(u,v)\bigr)=u^3(u-4\cos v)\sin v\ .$$
The end result then would be
$$\int_D\psi(u,v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)\ ;$$
but note that the last integral is only seemingly $=0$ by symmetry. In reality it does not exist since it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: I have not learned about pullback yet, do you happen to see any other ways to solve it?

Comment: Also is the last intergral missing an extra intergral sign? Should there be two?

Comment: One only writes two integral signs when one replaces a domain integral by two nested integrals, using Fubini's theorem. – Maybe you need an Advanced Calculus course before tackling this problem.